# Document.getElementById Error on .js file

Tags: drupal

document.getElementById error

```
Drupal.behaviors.Menu = {
attach: function () {

  var url = window.location.href;
  var baseUrl =  Drupal.settings.baseUrl;
  var page1 = baseUrl+'/path/page1';
  var page2 = baseUrl+'/path/page2';
  var page3 = baseUrl+'/path/page3';

  if($(".classname").length < 3) {      
    $( "#hook" ).append("<a class='classname' href='' id='page1_id'>page 1</a>");
    $( "#hook" ).append("<a class='classname' href='' id='page2_id'>page 2</a>");
    $( "#hook" ).append("<a class='classname' href='' id='page3_id'>page 3</a>");
  }
  if(url == baseUrl+'/path') {

    document.getElementById("page1_id").href = page1;
    document.getElementById("page2_id").href = page2;
    document.getElementById("page2_id").href = page3;      
  }   
}
};
```

Please dont confuse between page1 is(var) and page1_id is(id).

in the above function I known it was a error near the if statement
if(url == base...)
this is the exact spot where it is going error.
so want to known where i'm making the mistake as (the error is like this below)

--> when I open that particular page and those are menu links which are hooked perfectly and when I click on the page1 it opens perfectly.

The problem is what ever page i open first keeps on coming for the next two pages.
Like if I click on page2 first, next page1 or page3 (still it shows page2).

after page refresh

if I click on page3 first, next page1 or page2 (still it shows page3).
as the document.getElementById is holding the previous URL only.

help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: kinda confusing to follow, can you make a fiddle with a minimal and verifiable example to show what error you're getting?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to mix JQuery and Javascript, you can select an element by ID in Query by doing `$("#id")`

Comment: No it's not, you just have to remember to wrap your elements before handling them to jquery and unwrap them to handle them as elements. There is nothing magical in jQuery that would suddenly make the rest of javascript behave different.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**For user understanding my url is like**
`http://site.localhost/path/page1` (similarly page2 and page3)

This needs to be changed according when moved to **staging and production**

`Below code solved my issue`

!warning watch out comments.

```
Drupal.behaviors.Menu = {
attach: function () {

  //var url = window.location.href;
  var baseUrl =  Drupal.settings.baseUrl;
  var page1 = baseUrl+'/path/page1';
  var page2 = baseUrl+'/path/page2';
  var page3 = baseUrl+'/path/page3';
  //modified
  var parts = windows.loaction.pathname.split('/');
  var query = parts[parts.length-1].split('.html');
  //added these two variables for splitting the url.

  if($(".classname").length < 3) {      
    $( "#hook" ).append("<a class='classname' href='' id='page1_id'>page 1</a>");
    $( "#hook" ).append("<a class='classname' href='' id='page2_id'>page 2</a>");
    $( "#hook" ).append("<a class='classname' href='' id='page3_id'>page 3</a>");
  }
  //if(url == baseUrl+'/path') {
  if(query[0] == 'path' || query[0] == 'page1' || query[0] == 'page2' || query[0] == 'page3'){

    document.getElementById("page1_id").href = page1;
    document.getElementById("page2_id").href = page2;
    document.getElementById("page2_id").href = page3;      
  }   
}
};
```